# Kendo Grid Server Side Grouping Not Working With OData

Tags: kendo-ui, odata

Trying to get server side grouping to work with Kendo Grid and OData.
I have a bit of an unusual situation, in that I don't want to use JSonP and would like for the end point to be in my MVC controller.  The application will then route the request to the api using the api past stored in config.

Controller Method Seen below:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetMaintenanceLogs()
    {
        var query = Request.QueryString.ToString();
        var results = proxy.GetMaintenanceLogs(query);
        results.AggregateResults = new List<Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.AggregateResult>();
        return Json(results); 
    }
```

Grid Configuration Seen below:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<FirstStrike.Maintenance.Services.Models.MaintenanceLog>()
    .Name("maintenanceLogGrid")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Custom()
        .Type("odata")
        .Transport(t => t.Read(r => r.Url("/History/GetMaintenanceLogs").Type(HttpVerbs.Get).DataType("json")))
        .Schema(a => a.Model(b =>
        {
            b.Id(c => c.MaintenanceLogId);
            b.Field("MaintenanceLogDate", typeof(DateTime));
            b.Field("MaintenanceTaskDesc", typeof(String));
            b.Field("MaintenanceUserName", typeof(String));
            b.Field("MaintenanceTaskParams", typeof(String));
        })
        .Data("Data")
        .Total("Total"))
        .ServerAggregates(true)
        .ServerSorting(true)
        .ServerPaging(true)
        .ServerFiltering(true)
        .PageSize(10)
    )
```

etc...

Proxy Method Seen below:

```
 public DataSourceResult GetMaintenanceLogs(String query)
    {
        var service = ServiceHelper.GetODataClaimService();
        var url = service.MaintenanceLogs.ToString();
        var qor = service.ExecuteSync<MaintenanceLog>(url + query);
        return new DataSourceResult() { Data = qor.ToList(), Total = Convert.ToInt32(qor.TotalCount) };
    }
```

The issue I'm running into is that everything works perfectly.  The query executes and retrieves 10 records and the total count.  The data is then passed back to the client where I receive a javascript error.

Error seen below:

cannot read property 'length' of undefined kendo grid

What am I missing here.
Is the expected output different than what I am sending?  Is it expecting OData response?  Are the Data and total ignored in the HTML Helper when OData is utilized.  Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Note - The Aggregate Results part above is not relevant.  It was accidentally left in from testing.  Also, I know that I can override the parameterMap in Kendo grid and merge with the sorts to allow this to work, but I'd rellay prefer to have a solid fix instead of a workaround.

Comment: Update - I am able to get the grid to render the results if I return and object like the following:  new { Total = results.Total, Data = results.Data, Group = new Object[] { new { aggregates = new Object[] { }, field = "MaintenanceUserName", hasSubGroups = false, items = results.Data } } };